# append string with matched substring

Tags: javascript, date, nan

Im having issues with formatting a string received from the Twitter API. Im using timeago plugin and returns NaN in IE 10. After hunting it down it seems to be because the time recieved is formatted like so:

> Tue Apr 02 14:27:31 +0000 2013

instead of:

> Tue Apr 02 14:27:31 2013 +0000

Anyone know a quick way of matching if this is present and then appending the string if it is?

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `splice` and `split` method to achive this.

```
var time="Tue Apr 02 14:27:31 +0000 2013";
var arr = time.split(" ");
var year = arr.splice(arr.length-1,1);
arr.splice(arr.length-1,0, year[0]);

//console.log(arr.join(" "));
```

Comment: True, this works as long as you always get the same input. If the input changes you're safer using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
Var dateStr; // your date string
Var index = dateStr.indexOf('+'); 

If (index === dateStr.length-5) {
    // you're in format two, what you wanted 
}
```

The caveat is that this date has to come in the way you displayed it.

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions you could use this:

```
var originalDate = "Tue Apr 02 14:27:31 +0000 2013";
// find the last two number blocks and swap them
var reformattedDate = originalDate.replace(/ (\+[0-9]+) ([0-9]{4})$/, "$2 $1");
```

This will switch the position of the last two number-blocks in the original date.

Also this method will not change dates that don't match the regular expression. If you get an originalDate that already has the format "2013 +0000" it will **not** be changed. ;)